# XCode 7 Won't Build for iPhone with JailCoder(?) Installed

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am currently trying run my project on my iPhone, but I get this error:

> /Users/jacobplatin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Help_STL-dygpwrqdnauiqrezzkktttkchmft/Build/Intermediates/Help STL.build/Debug-iphoneos/Help STL.build/Script-50524F424C454D533F.sh: line 4: /Library/JailCoder/Entitlements/Entitlements.py: No such file or directory

I've tried unpatching the project, but I am unable because it just says "error" and when I try to unpatch XCode, Jailcoder crashes unexpectedly.

I never used Jailcoder past trying to run it once on XCode 6, and any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You have a script in your build phases that is looking for a file called "Entitlements.py".  Do you have that file?  If so, where is it located?

Comment: @PhillipMills I fixed the issue, it was actually under the 'Run Script' section; I just deleted that code and it worked fine, thanks